# NEO4j duplicated return using optional match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In the cypher query we want to fetch all sorts of data from the user. At this point we are using optional match to fetch the relationships from a user.

```
MATCH (person:Person { Id : xxxx })
OPTIONAL MATCH (person)-[:NEXT*]->(element)
OPTIONAL MATCH (person)-[:WROTE_COMMENT]->(comment)
RETURN person, collect(element) as element, collect(comment) as comment
```

The problem is that this query returns all elements duplicated for each comment that is found. We could fix that using a distinct but then the elements can no longer be added twice to the list.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Split the query into 2 steps using `WITH`, to avoid doing a cartesian product between the 2 lists:

```
MATCH (person:Person { Id : xxxx })
OPTIONAL MATCH (person)-[:NEXT*]->(element)
WITH person, collect(element) AS element
OPTIONAL MATCH (person)-[:WROTE_COMMENT]->(comment)
RETURN person, element, collect(comment) as comment
```

Comment: Thxs Frank! That seems to work. The only thing is that if I extend this by lets say 10 OPTIONAL matches, I have to put all objects in the WITH everytime.

Is that the only way?

Comment: I'm afraid so, if you don't split using `WITH`, you'll have a cartesian product, and if you don't list all objects, they won't be visible to the next step.

Comment: I will figure something out to get the With list complete. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm curious if anyone has come up with a more elegant solution since 2016?